# Chain rule for functions of two variables twice

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKv7e.png

Question 10

(a) Consider the function f given by:

$f(x, y)$ = $x^3$ + $3xy^2$ + $12y^2$ − $75x$.

(i) Calculate the first and second order partial derivatives $fx$, $fy,$ $fxx$, $fyy$, $fxy$,
and $fyx$.

(ii) Find and classify all of the stationary points of $f$

(b) Suppose that $z = g(x, y)$, $x = s+t$, and $y = st$, where all first and second order
partial derivatives of g exist and are continuous.

Show that
$\frac{∂^2z}{∂s∂t}$ =
$\frac{∂^2g}{∂x^2}$ +
$x\frac{∂^2g}{∂x∂y}$ +
$y\frac{∂^2g}{∂y^2}$ +
$\frac{∂g}{∂y}$

Can someone please explain how to do question 10b, I know that 
$\frac{∂x}{∂s}$ = 1, $\frac{∂x}{∂t}$ = 1, $\frac{∂y}{∂s}$ = t, $\frac{∂y}{∂t}$ = s

but I have no idea what to do from here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
z_t 
&= g_x \, x_t + g_y \, y_t
= g_x + g_y \, s \\
z_{st}
&= g_{xx} \, x_s + g_{yx} \, y_s + (g_{xy} \, x_s + g_{yy} \, y_s) s + g_y \\
&= g_{xx} + g_{xy} \, (t + s) + g_{yy}\,ts + g_y \\
&= g_{xx} + g_{xy}\, x + g_{yy} \, y + g_y
\end{align}